# Can an index on a subfield cover queries on projections of that field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Imagine you have a schema like:

```
[{
  name: "Bob",
  naps: [{
    time: 2019-05-01T15:35:00,
    location: "sofa"
  }, ...]
 }, ...
]
```

So lots of people, each with a few dozen naps. You want to find out 'what days do people take the most naps?', so you index `naps.time`, and then query with:

```
aggregate([
  {$unwind: naps}, 
  {$group: { _id: {$day: "$naps.time"}, napsOnDay: {"$sum": 1 } }
])
```

But when doing `explain()`, mongo tells me no index was used in this query, when clearly the index on the time `Date` field could have been. Why is this? How can I get mongo to use the index for the more optimal query?

Comment: Aggregations only use indexes when there is a $match or $sort stage at the beginning of the pipeline. See [this answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927912/how-can-aggregate-break-an-index/57928139#57928139) .

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it. Any idea _why_? If using it provides better performance, is that not - as mr. Banner might say - an absolute win?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes stores pointers to actual documents, and can only be used when working with a material document (i.e. the document that is actually stored on disk).

`$match` or `$sort` does not mutate the actual documents, and thus indexes can be used in these stages.

In contrast, `$unwind`, `$group`, or any other stages that changes the actual document representations basically loses the connection between the index and the material documents.

Additionally, when those stages are processed without `$match`, you're basically saying that you want to process the whole collection. There is no point in using the index if you want to process the whole collection.